# How to insert an untitled hyperlink with RestructuredText?

Tags: hyperlink, restructuredtext

With RestructuredText, I'd just like to insert a link where the address is the text of link. Like this: https://www.example.com/example-of-link.html

I just want the link to appear in the text, with no modification, no title, just the raw link. I can't find a way to do this. All the examples in the doc give titles to the links. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering my own question: you just have to write the link and that's it, like this:

```
 https://www.example.com/example-of-link.html
```

I always seem to forget that and I waste time searching for it. At least now the answer will be on Stackoverflow.